# How to check if a Ruby function (not a method) exists

Tags: ruby

In `Sinatra` gem there are `production?` and `development?` function, 
how to check if a script was ever requiring `Sinatra` 
or if there are `production?` and `development?` function ever defined?

possibly better explanation:

```
 script1.rb:
 # there is possibility that this script contains "require 'sinatra'"
 # note that sinatra defines 'production?' and 'development?' function

 script2.rb:
 # there is possibility that this script already has defining 'production?' function

 script3.rb:
 require_relative 'script1'
 require_relative 'script2'
 ...
 require_relative 'scriptX'
 # in this script, how to know if there are at least one script that has already defining 'production?' function?
```

Comment: What you are calling functions are actually methods.

Comment: There are no functions in Ruby, only instance methods. Can you clarify your question, please? Are you talking about `Proc`s?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! using `defined?`

```
require 'ap'

ap defined? production? 
# nil

def production?
end

ap defined? production?
# 'method'
```